# Automate git commands and don't enter username+password every time

Tags: git, bash, shell, github

I use the following commands to update my application in the `nginx` `ubuntu` server

```
cd /opt/app/
sudo git fetch --all
sudo git reset --hard origin/master
sudo npm install
pm2 start npm -- start
```

For `sudo git fetch --all`, I need to enter my github username + password and sometimes the password of my ubuntu account.

Does anyone know if it is possible to automate this? I don't want to enter these information every time.

**Edit 1:** For the record, I did the following steps:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

It does generate `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Then

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
kill $SSH_AGENT_PID
```

Then, I did `less ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and copy the content and did [this](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) to github.

Then, I re-entered the server, now `sudo git fetch --all` does not require username + password.

Comment: i guess you could try setting up ssh certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SSH keys and SSH to never enter credentials again. Just take a look at the [Github help](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/).

You can also put this config to cache your Github http credentials in Git :

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```